# Power Query M Power BI Search Value between ranges from other query

Tags: powerbi, powerquery, m

Hi I have the query with ranges:
[image: RangesMerged]

I need to find if the if the value from Consolidate query column to_be_filtered fits any of the ranges from the RangesMerged query

[image: to_be_filtered]

`List.Transform( { Number.From([Date From])..Number.From([Date To]) }, each Date.From(_) )`

Comment: Can you precise how you want the filter column to be filtered.  Here, we have a single column result we don’t know you want it yo be computed. You also put in the question a query which is different from the result screenshot.

Comment: i need to check for every entry in to_be_filtered from Consolidate query if it fits any ranges from RangesMerged (if it is between any startRange and endRange)

Comment: And what should be the output ? A table which contains only these entries ? A table with TRUE or FALSE depending of the test ?

Comment: True or False is enough

Comment: I give you both

Answer (score 0):

Here is script which filter a table. Only the lines which are in ANY of the Range table are outputed:

```ml
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="To_be_filtered"]}[Content],
    Typed = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"to_be_filtered", Int64.Type}}),
    Filtered = Table.SelectRows(Typed, (row) => Table.MatchesAnyRows(Ranges, 
         (range) => range[startRange] <= row[to_be_filtered] 
                and row[to_be_filtered] <= range[endRange]))
in
    Filtered
```

You need the "Ranges" table to have a corresponding query connection named `Ranges`.

You should fix the test depending is you want the comparisons to be inclusive or not. (Here, start=1, end=3 matches 1,2,3).

If you want all the entries, but with a column which indicates if the number is in ANY range:

```ml
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="To_be_filtered"]}[Content],
    Typed = Table.TransformColumnTypes(Source,{{"to_be_filtered", Int64.Type}}),
    Filtered = Table.AddColumn(Typed, "included", (row) => Table.MatchesAnyRows(Ranges,
              (range) => range[startRange] <= row[to_be_filtered] 
                     and row[to_be_filtered] <= range[endRange]))
in
    Filtered
```